# How to update numpy column where column condition met?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

If I have the following:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 1],
              [1, 3],
              [4, 4]])
```

And want to update the column value if a column condition is met.  For example if the 2nd column value is greater than 2, then replace only that column value with 9.

```
a = [[0, 1],
     [1, 9],
     [4, 9]]
```

I would have thought this would work, but it updates all the values in that row.

```
a[a[:,1] > 2] = 9
```

But it replaces all the values in the row.

```
a =[[0, 1],
    [9, 9],
    [9, 9]]
```

I'm guessing I'm missing some understanding of how the boolean indexing is being created here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 1],
               [1, 3],
               [4, 4]])

a[:,1]=  np.where(a[:,1]>2, 9, a[:,1])

print(a)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 9],
       [4, 9]])
```

**why your code not working**

try printing out `print(a[a[:,1] > 2])`

it will give output as:

```
[[1 3]
 [4 4]]
```

It will check for 2nd index if it is greater than 2 it will return an entire row.